# Is there a way to see characters typed for an su password

Tags: linux, bash, su

I am writing a bash script that may need to su to run a command.  Something like this-

echo "Installing the XYZ System"
echo "Please enter the root password-"
su -c "java -cp ./Installer.jar com.company.FmMain ; exit"

Is there a way to have su print characters (asterisks or something) so the user has some visual feedback as they type the password?

Comment: Yeah. Grab the source of "su", rewrite it so it does feedback and make the user install it.

Comment: I don't think there is with any standard command, but you might find more help on superuser.com.

Comment: Not possible without modifying the source code.

Answer (score 1):

You'll have to read the password into a variable first, outside of `su`.  See the question [How do I echo stars (*) when reading password with `read`?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1923435/how-do-i-put-stars-into-read) for an example of using `read` to accomplish this.

Then, you'll have to use `expect` to pass this password in to the password prompt that `su` presents.  See the question [How do I use expect to connect via ssh to a system and change the password of the host system?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4566830/how-do-i-use-expect-to-connect-via-ssh-to-a-system-and-change-the-password-of-th) for an example of doing something similar.

Comment: Excellent, thank you very much.  Those links are exactly what I was looking for.

Answer (score 1):

I would not recomend masking password in Linux it goes against expected normal behaviour and will likely confuse users, especially if they are experienced Linux users. The standard way of reading passwords is to turn off echoing and disable processing of special characters like escape sequences etc. before accepting the password (this is usally done through setting terminal attributes - tcsetattr and the like), this is the way su works.

There are standard library functions such as getpass which do this for you:
http://www.gnu.org/s/hello/manual/libc/getpass.html

Trying to implement your own methods of doing this has potential security implimentations. I'd strongly warn aginst this.